# How should i go with modeling this pistol grip piece?

Tags: modeling

im trying to make this pistol grip or at least somewhat resemble this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the image in your 3D view and draw its profile:

[image]

Extrude the mesh, use a *Mirror* modifier:

[image]

Work the geometry in 3D:

[image]

Give it some additional edge loops in order to sharp some edges:

[image]

Comment: ay! thanks man, i appreciate the step by step process you gave.

Comment: instead of building the shape and then using the knife to make the indent, i started off with the shape of the indent, and then extrude to create the shape of the body, but i want to define the imprint a little more.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/aXxb2Co

Comment: you are using a lot of edge loops, I'm not sure they are very useful, it makes it more difficult

Comment: ok, i"ll lessen the amount

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Wvu2kxf

Comment: yes it's better in my opinion, don't forget these two part that you can get with extrusions: https://zupimages.net/up/20/39/cknp.jpg

Comment: ive actually went about to modeling the rest of the gun! i didnt so the two parts yet, because i just saw your comment, but i thank you for your help! mind telling me what you think so far? There are some parts of it that i was a bit lazy on, but i'll go back to them once complete with the whole model

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Kpl3zsvN" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Kpl3zsvN/)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/nh7dXSo

Comment: Maybe join all the parts unless you have good reason to keep them separate? I think there are several issues like ngons and tris that you should try to avoid, or useless edges, also make sure that your normals are correctly filpped. Is it for a game or for a Blender image or animation? In the latter, use the Subdivision Surface to have a smooth appearance

Comment: the model is for a game i plan to create.

Comment: Oh ok in that case you won't be able to use the Subdivision Surface modifier

Comment: the foreground is the gun with subsdivision, the one behind that is all peices joined together.https://imgur.com/a/3ETGf3K

Comment: I don't know a lot about games, I guess the choice between low-poly and high-poly is both an esthetic and technical choice

Comment: yeah, this model is meant for more being seen closer up, so i just want it to at least look pleasing to the eye when holding, i just hope the weird shading doesn't make it look too bad.